# Get HTTP response code?

Tags: php, web-services, apache, get, http-headers

So, I have a short function (used to initialize web services) which includes a try-catch statement:

```
try {
  WebServices::create($this->nameWS);
}
catch (Exception $e) { 
  // Get name/number of http response code
}
```

What I'm trying to do inside the `catch` is get the reason for failure - the HTTP response (e.g. `502 bad gateway` or `504 gateway time out` etc).

I'm frustrated because I seem to be able to get every other piece of information possible, except for this part.

What I've tried to use so far:

1. **[http_response_code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)** (returns undefined).
2. **[get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)** (My URL is a WSDL. This does not return anything, it just takes 30 seconds and I recieve a timeout message).
3. [**getallheaders**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php). (Includes everything except the HTTP response name/number).

None of which work.

**Note:** I'm actually testing the `catch` part of the statement by changing my WSDL **while logged in** and trying to call it, e.g. from:

```
"http://83.97.20.135:8080/services/e?wsdl"
```

to

```
"http://localhost:8080/services/e?wsdl"
```

in my `webservices.xml`.

Comment: What kind of different `Exceptions` does `Webservices::create` throw? If it doesn't give you any info maybe the best you can do is `400 Bad Request`?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen 504 gateway time out is what happens. That's the only one currently, but I can't actually get it inside any variable - $this, $e, getHeaders etc.

Comment: What is `WebServices` exactly? It's not part of PHP...

Comment: @deceze I have it as Webservices.class.php, basically it's where all the webservice related code is

Comment: ...aaaaaand what does that class do? How does it communicate with the actual web service? Does *it* catch the response code somehow?

Comment: @deceze From what I can see is it creates a new web service instance, initializes it and calls it. There are a couple of functions in that file that may be of use to me (getInstance, getNamespace, getTypeWS) but I don't know how to call them from this file. I was assuming I could get the HTTP headers at anytime, but it doesn't seem like I can

Comment: We don't know what this class is or does either. Unless you provide more information about it, we can't help. Maybe it offers some method to get the response, maybe it doesn't. We can tell even less than you.